# Como funciona o ataque meet-in-the-middle?

Tags: criptografia

Estava procurando sobre o antigo 3DES e resolvi pesquisar porque não existe 2DES, encontrei poucas informações, *até porque não "existiu" de fato 2DES*.

Apesar ser abreviado também como MITM, ele não tem relação com o *Man-in-the-middle*, comumente abreviado de mesma maneira, pelo que procurei ele é aplicável sempre que se faz:

```
E(K, E(K, M))
```

Por isso o 3DES utiliza o formato no minimo o formato de `E(K1, D(K2, E(K1, M)))`, usando ao menos duas chaves (`K1` e `K2`) de 56 bits, pode utilizar também três chaves distintas. Porém pesquisando ele ainda seria vulnerável a este ataque de *Meet-in-the-middle*, porém com um custo maior do que o "2DES", que faria na época ser seguro o suficiente.

<sub>*Considerando que `E` seja encriptação, `D` seja decriptação, `K` seja chave, `M` seja a mensagem.*</sub>

**Afinal o que é meet-in-the-middle?**

Comment: Dahora, cara. Gosto muito de ver esse tipo de pergunta por aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matemática por trás do ataque é mais complexa do que o que eu vou por aqui na resposta, mas o princípio no qual se baseia é simples.

Algoritmos como o "Double DES" e o Triple DES possuem múltiplas etapas de criptografia, com chaves distintas. Isso aumenta a segurança porque o elemento criminoso que for querer quebrar sua criptografia tem que brutalizar mais de uma chave.

Vamos fazer uma conta simples: se existem *n* chaves em uma única etapa, eu tenho que testar *n* combinações possíveis para quebrar uma chave na força bruta. Mas se existem *n* chaves em uma etapa e *m* em outra, o meu esforço é de testar *n * m* combinações, o que pode ser um número muito maior.

Só que matematicamente, se chamarmos:

- os dados originais de D;
- os dados criptografados de C;
- a função de encriptação de ENC;
- a função de decriptação de DEC;
- e as chaves usadas de *m* e *n*;

Temos que:

> C = ENC<sub>m</sub>(ENC<sub>n</sub>(D))

A malandragem está em usar álgebra para brincar com a equação acima:

> DEC<sub>m</sub>(C) = DEC<sub>m</sub>(ENC<sub>m</sub>(ENC<sub>n</sub>(D)))
>   (primeira equação, decripta ambos os lados com m)

E logo em seguida:

> DEC<sub>m</sub>(C) = ENC<sub>n</sub>(D)
>   (Corta uma encriptação com m seguida por uma decriptação com m do lado direito)

Fez sentido até aqui? Você não precisa testar *m * n* combinações, você só precisa testar *m + n*... O que é muito menor. Na verdade, quanto mais *m* e *n* crescem, maior é a diferença entre as duas formas.

Se ainda não deu pra perceber, lembre-se, você não precisa entender o resultado da encriptação/decriptação intermediária pra saber que um par de chaves deu certo ;)

Não preciso nem dizer o que acontece se a mesma chave for usada nas duas etapas, né? :D

E é por isso que o nome do ataque é encontro no meio. Você ataca o algoritmo de um lado (com a cifra) e do outro (com os dados originais), e no meio você encontra o tesouro.

Agora você pode dizer "ah, mas o atacante pode não ter os meus dados originais, afinal eu encriptei". Bom, isso é um caso de uso. Mas pense no caso em que o atacante obtém uma amostra de um texto plano e do resultado de encriptação com as suas chaves. Ele agora pode adivinhar as chaves e decriptar tudo mais que você tiver encriptado com essas chaves.

E por fim, é por isso que a indústria foi direto do DES para o DES triplo. Quando estavam por fazer um novo algoritmo perceberam que o DES duplo seria muito vulnerável a esse tipo de ataque. O triplo também é, mas é menos vulnerável (adicione mais uma etapa de encriptação) - a ponto de ter sido aceito por um tempo como um bom padrão. Não sei como está hoje.

Crédito onde é merecido, [tirei várias informações da wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack).