# PHP - encryptar/ decryptar dados

Tags: php

Eu estou usando encriptação AES-128 para mensagens de utilizadores, mas eu pretendia encryptar com mais Layers.
Exemplo :

```
        Layer 1: encryptacao aes-128
        Layer 2: “outra encryptacao”.
```

Acham que é boa ideia proteger desta forma? Se sim, que encryptacao posso usar para encryptar e desincriptar

Answer (score 0):

Não há porque fazer isso, ninguém faz isso já que o AES é seguro.

Se você não quer usar AES-128 use o AES-256 ou AES-192. Se você não confia no AES, principalmente se você não tem um processador com suporte para AES-NI, use outra cifra, como o Serpent-256, Salsa20 ou ChaCha20.

O único ganho de segurança que teria é se o algoritmo, isoladamente, é vulnerável a buscas exaustivas, como é o caso do DES. Neste caso existe o 3DES que faz exatamente 2 encriptações e 1 decriptação, mas ainda existe o problema de [meet-in-the-middle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225499/como-funciona-o-ataque-meet-in-the-middle).

O 3DES foi criado porque o DES é vulnerável a busca exaustiva. Usar o mesmo processo para o AES é inútil, o AES não tem o mesmo problema. Inclusive, o AES é segura até contra computadores quânticos, se prefere cifras de fluxo o Salsa20 também é, [segundo a PQCrypto](https://pqcrypto.eu.org/docs/initial-recommendations.pdf).

---

Acredito que existe outros problemas que pode estar preocupado, como a integridade da informação ou o armazenamento das chaves, por exemplo.

Comment: Exato, eu quero que a encryptacao seja super segura. Pois o objetivo das mensagens è serem anonymas.

Já agora, que tipo de verificaçoes eu deva fazer para proteger um Form?